# VMWare SQL 2008 R2 Windows 7 High memory usage

Tags: iis, sql, vmware-esx, memory-usage

I have a windows 7 64 bit installed in a VM which runs SQL Server 2008 R2 and IIS7. 
The server itself has 12 gigs of memory and is equipped with a dual core intel xeon @ 2.50 GHz.

The problem (I am not really sure if it is a problem yet) is that the task manager constantly shows me 8.50 GB in use while no process is consuming this amount of memory.

[image]

I took a look at [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/115982/weird-memory-usage-in-windows-server-2008-r2) question which was talking about the sql locked page allocations memory. What I found though is that those values are normal - around 85 mb. Here is a screenshot of the command

```
select * from sys.dms_os_process_memorys
```

[image]

However based on the above picture I also see a `total_virtual_space_kb` of around 8.50 GB.
Last, I ran RamMap which shows me that there are around 8.50 Gb in use by **"Driver locked"**. Elsewhere it was suggested that this "Driver locked" memory is in use by VMWare.

I have a few questions:

1) Is this memory really consumed or will it be released to another process upon need? I have noticed that the server is noticeably slow so I am wondering if that has something to do with it. Further, I get commonly `OutOfMemoryExceptions` being thrown by my asp.net processes.

2) Who is allocating/using this memory? SQL or VMWare?

3) Is there a way for me to fix that issue?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like ESX(i)'s balloon driver is locking the memory. How much RAM have you assigned to the VM? How much to other *running* VMs on the same host? How much RAM does the host have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this is a result of the hypervisor (ESX/i) "balloon" driver in action. The balloon driver works via the VMware tools, requesting a certain amount of memory from the guest OS without actually using it within the guest OS. This allows the hypervisor to use the memory elsewhere.

Ballooning is usually a good thing for a number of reasons, but with MSSQL it tends to be a bit of a hassle, because the SQL engine is very good at memory management itself.

Here's some more info on this which may explain better than I can:

- http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/virtualization2/q-how-can-i-tell-how-much-memory-the-dynamic-memory-balloon-driver-is-using-
- http://www.jimmcleod.net/blog/index.php/2008/06/10/vmware-balloon-drivers-and-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

Please check the memory reservation setting for all your VMs. it should be set to unlimited or to the max memory that is set on your server.

Go to vm settings, Tab resources. select memory and check the limitation.

Answer (score -1):

SQL Server has to be limited in memory usage as best practice first. The best way to see how much memory your SQL server really need use perfmon:

> Before reducing the max server memory value, use Performance Monitor 
>   to examine the SQLServer:Buffer Manager performance object while under 
>   a load, and note the current values of the Stolen pages and Reserved 
>   pages counters. These counters report memory as the number of 8K 
>   pages. max server memory should be set above the sum of these two 
>   values to avoid out-of-memory errors. An approximate value for the 
>   lowest reasonable max server memory setting (in MB) is ([Stolen pages]
>   + [Reserved pages])/ 100

Source: TechNet (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms178067(SQL.90).aspx)

Comment: Sorry, but "as best practice" should be named "as best practice on small and very small installations". Where I work, every sql server has his own machine - either pyhysical or virtual - and the autoamtic limit is very fine here.Limiting it only makes sense ins hared environments and / or when you ahve multiple instances clusters playing around with memory usage.

Comment: I disagree. SQL Server tends to over commit memory and not release it to other processes. This server runs IIS too, so memory should be limited.

Comment: No reason to disagree - if IIS is running, this is a small or very small installation and a shared environment (i.e. other significant applications). Then it applies, as I said. Still, it is not best practice in general, because there are a lot larger servers than you likely ever ahve seen (currently working on a 96gb RAM, 96 physical thread machine with 21.000gb data storage - there is NOTHING else there than the database server).